# can we use transaction mangament like transaction definition (required or Requiresnew) when we use session bean with JDBC?

Tags: ejb

Can we specify the transactionManagent/transactionAttribute(like required or Requiresnew )  to mention how the Container must manage transactions for a method 
when a client invokes the method of session bean with JDBC. if yes can someone point me a brief example of that.

I am under impression that declarative transactionManagent in session bean can be used 
only when we are using session beans with Entity beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to specify transaction demarcation annotations on session EJBs or on their individual methods using the [@TransactionAttribute](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) annotation or via entries in `ejb-jar.xml`.

You can find the basics addressed in the [Java EE tutorial on container-managed transactions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). Other places to obtain examples would be the OpenEJB project, which describes the [usage of the annotations](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/transaction-annotations.html), and also [testing for session EJB methods that uses these annotations](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/testing-transactions-example.html).

As far, as the scope of declarative transaction management uses are concerned, they are not restricted to entity beans (if you are referring to EJB 2.x entity beans, which no sensible project would use nowadays). You could use them with lower-level protocols like plain JDBC or other transactional protocols, and with higher-level frameworks like JPA, as long as the underlying datasources that you are using, support transactional access, i.e. allows for enlisting and delisting of the datasources in the transactions using the JTA APIs.

Comment: Thanks Vineet But the term BMP and CMP are used ion terms of entity beans right?

Comment: Well, I would suggest looking up sources of information that are current and upto date. Unless you are working on an EJB 2.x project, you should not worry about these terms in an EJB 3.x project. The concept of entity beans no longer exists from Java EE 5 onwards (which has been available for at least 5 years now). One would use entities, which are defined by the JPA specification, instead of entity beans which were defined by the EJB specification. The EJB specification only deals with session EJBs and MDBs as of today. JPA entities can be used outside a Java EE container as well.